# Removing empty bars in stacked barchart

Tags: r

Hello I am trying to remove the empty bars which show up in the stacked barchart. I already created a new data frame with zero values removed but it continues to plot the black lines. Here is the code:

```
OTU.melt = melt(SHB.OTU.stack_merge.1000, id = c("type"))

OTUmelt_reorder <- OTU.melt %>% mutate(type = fct_relevel(type, "A", "B", "C", "E", "F", "G", "D", "H"))

OTUmelt_reorder.no0 <- OTUmelt_reorder %>% filter(value != 0)


OTU.melt.x = ggplot(OTUmelt_reorder.no0, aes(x = type, fill = variable, y = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", colour = "black") +

  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, size = 14, colour = "black", vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1, face= "bold"), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"), legend.title = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold"), 
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold", colour = "black"), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black", size = 12, face = "bold")) + 
  labs(x = "", y= "# Sequences", fill = "Family", 
       caption = "A = nest exterior surface
     B = 5cm beneath nest exterior
     C = egg chamber - top 
     E = egg chamber - center
     F = egg chamber - bottom
     G = egg surface
     D = surrounding water
H = nest dripline")
```

[image]

Thank you

Comment: `object 'OTU.melt' not found`

Comment: You have to drop the empty factor levels (e.g. `OTUmelt_reorder.no0$type <- droplevels(OTUmelt_reorder.no0$type)`

Comment: Sorry the droplevels did not work